# ANDROID : Webview doesn't take full width

Tags: android, html, webview, width

As you see below i have a Layout with a Webview and an Imageview in it. The webview must take 0,8as weight (80% of width) and the Imageview should take 0.2 (20% of width). This should work perfectly however the webview doesn't take the full width, it only takes half of the width. On the Samsung Tab even less...

I have searched various solutions through stackoverflow and the internet. Most people set you must setLoadWithOverviewMode, which loads the webview completely zoomed. And this must be combined with setUseWideViewPort which forces it to take the dimensions of the webview.

I have been toying with this for a day now, if somebody could provide some help it would be much appreciated :)

This is the HTML :

```
<html> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=40></meta>
    <body style='background-color: transparent; color: Grey; font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; font-size: 10pt; width: 258px; word-wrap: break-word;'>
     <div align='left'>When changing... 
       <span style='background-color: transparent; color: #a8c916; font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; font-size: 10pt; word-wrap: break-word;'>%d punten</span> 
       <span style='background-color: transparent; color: Grey; font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; font-size: 10pt; word-wrap: break-word;'>%@</span>
     </div>
</body>
```

Java :

```
vh.textTagline.setInitialScale(40);
vh.textTagline.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
vh.textTagline.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

The XML :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textTagline"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="17dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need make the following changes to your xml:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textTagline"
        android:layout_weight="8"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="17dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The width should be 0dp for layout_weight to work.